# Dynamically changing the widgets/page based on function parameters in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate a Shiny App which is dependent on some arguments of a function. If I use the `quantmod` package to download data and then use the `TTR` package to make some data modifications I would like to change the `numericInput()` (add / take away inputs) depending on a dropdown value being selected.

I would like to replicate something similar to the following.

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

sym <- "GOOG"

data <- getSymbols(Symbols = sym, src = "yahoo", index.class = "POSIXct", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2019-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)

SMA(Cl(data), n = 5)
EMA(Cl(data), n = 5)
WMA(Cl(data), n = 5, wts = 1:5)
```

Where I have some data and I apply 3 functions to the data `SMA`, `EMA` and `WMA`. The `SMA` and `EMA` are simple since it only takes a single argument `n`, however the `WMA` takes `n` and an additional argument `wts`.

I created a basic Shiny app where I am modifying the `Widgets` tab. I create 4 fields. A simple text field, a dropdown menu, a argument specifying `n`and a weights field.

I would like to show the "correct" specified entry fields depending on the selected choice from the dropdown menu. That is, show `selectedN` for all choices since the functions `SMA`, `EMA` and `WMA` all depend on it, however once the `WMA` is selected I would like the user to be able to enter in some weights/values.

I am having difficulties here.

1. With adding multiple weights/numeric values and passing it to the `wts` value in the `reactive({})` part of the code.
2. Find the most suitable method of applying this dynamic input to the data in the `server`. What I was thinking about was to apply `if` statements based on the function names but I think I have seen *easier* methods on some shiny tutorials. - So depending on the function from the dropdown specified I would like to present to the user the arguments from the function selected.

Any push in the right direction would be great.

Shiny Code:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
            menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            # First tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                    fluidRow(
                        box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                        
                        box(
                            title = "Controls",
                            sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                        )
                    )
            ),
            
            # Second tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                    fluidPage(
                        titlePanel(title = h2("Algo Backtester", align = "center")),
                        sidebarPanel(
                            textInput("sym", "Symbol", "MSFT"),
                            selectInput(inputId = "selectDropdown", label = "dropdownChoice", choices = c("SMA", "EMA", "WMA")),
                            numericInput(inputId = "selectN", label = "selectedN", value = 3),
                            numericInput(inputId = "weights", label = "Weights", value = 1)              # stuck here with adding multiple weights
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                            tableOutput("modData"),
                            
                        )
                    )
            )
            )
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    set.seed(122)
    histdata <- rnorm(500)
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
        hist(data)
    })
    
    output$out <- reactive({
        selectedDropdown <- input$selectDropdown
        data <- getSymbols(Symbols = input$sym, src = "yahoo", index.class = "POSIXct", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2019-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
        n = input$selectN
        wts = 1:5                                   # would like to modify here                             
        # Apply selection to "data"
        if(selectDropdown == "SMA"){
            SMA(Cl(data), n = n)
        } 
        if(selectDropdown == "EMA"){
            EMA(Cl(data), n = n)
        }
        if(selectDropdown == "WMA"){
            WMA(Cl(data), n = n, wts = wts)
        }
        
        
    })
    
    output$modData <- renderTable({
        head(output$out())
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically generate UI elements, you need to use `renderUI` in the server and assign it to a `uiOutput` in the UI function. As you only want to render the element if the `WMA` function is selected, you can use `req(input$selectDropdown == "WMA")` in the `renderUI` call. `req` evaluates if an expression is "truthy" and only executes the following code if the condition is met.

As you only have 3 different choices of functions, I think your use of `if` clauses is perfectly fine here.

You had some other problems with your code:

- if you generate a `reactive` function, you just assign it to a function name, not to `output$functionname`
- typos with `selectDropdown` instead of `selectedDropdown`
- I don't know what are sensible inputs for the `wts`argument. `numericInput` only returns one value, but you need a vector with the length of `x`. I just used `rep(input$weights, times = nrow(data))` to make it work

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              fluidPage(
                titlePanel(title = h2("Algo Backtester", align = "center")),
                sidebarPanel(
                  textInput("sym", "Symbol", "MSFT"),
                  selectInput(inputId = "selectDropdown", label = "dropdownChoice", choices = c("SMA", "EMA", "WMA")),
                  numericInput(inputId = "selectN", label = "selectedN", value = 3),
                  uiOutput(outputId = "weights_UI")
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  tableOutput("modData"),
                  
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$weights_UI <- renderUI({
    req(input$selectDropdown == "WMA")
    
    numericInput(inputId = "weights", label = "Weights", value = 1)
  })
  
  out <- reactive({
    selectedDropdown <- input$selectDropdown
    data <- getSymbols(Symbols = input$sym, src = "yahoo", index.class = "POSIXct", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2019-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
    
    n = input$selectN
    # wts = 1:5                                   # would like to modify here                             
    # Apply selection to "data"
    if(selectedDropdown == "SMA"){
      SMA(Cl(data), n = n)
    } 
    if(selectedDropdown == "EMA"){
      EMA(Cl(data), n = n)
    }
    if(selectedDropdown == "WMA"){
      WMA(Cl(data), n = n, wts = rep(input$weights, times = nrow(data)))
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$modData <- renderTable({
    head(out())
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```